# jq: detect if input is a list or a dict

Tags: json, jq

I need the similar CSV output for both single dict and list of dicts.

But I can't understand, how to make it with `jq`.

Case 1: input is a **dict**:

```sh
$ curl --silent 'https://uinames.com/api/?amount=1' 
{"name":"Daniel","surname":"Gligor","gender":"male","region":"Romania"}
```

and my corresponding `jq` expression:

```sh
$ curl --silent 'https://uinames.com/api/?amount=1' |
  jq -r '[.name, .surname] | @csv'
"Angel","Sîrghie"
```

Case 2: input is a **list of dicts**:

```sh
$ curl --silent 'https://uinames.com/api/?amount=2' 
[{"name":"Summer","surname":"Lee","gender":"female","region":"Canada"},{"name":"Július","surname":"Dzurjanin","gender":"male","region":"Slovakia"}]
```

My expression:

```sh
$ curl --silent 'https://uinames.com/api/?amount=2' |
> jq -r '.[] | [.name, .surname] | @csv'
"Francisca","Navarro"
"Larisa","Dănescu"
```

I tried a lot of variants with `if/else`, `select()`, `path()`, `//`, etc.. Unfortunately, I can't create working expresion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is your friend:

```
if type == "array" then .[] else . end
| [.name, .surname]
| @csv'
```